# how to make python recgnize these two lines as one sentence

Tags: python

how can i make python recognize these two lines as one line because they are one sentence. I'm reading these from a text file. So if i want to check if the word is in a sentence and if it is it should print these two lines because they are one sentence. But my code is only printing the first line.

```
//! hello ID x86357 this is python programming language it's a very nice 
//! programming language.
```

Code

```
with open("test_file.txt", "r") as csvfile:
    for row in csvfile:
        if 'ID' in row:
            print(row)
```

Expected code

```
//! hello this is python programming language it's a very nice 
//! programming language.
```

Actual result

```
//! hello this is python programming language it's a very nice
```

Comment: What is your definition of "one sentence"? Any amount of characters until a period `'.'` is encountered?

Comment: @CoryKramer I think "one sentence" starts with a line containing `ID` and ends before the next occurrence of a line containing `ID`.

Comment: You are checking if a line contains the word ID and only in this case you are printing the line. Now the next line doesn't contains ID so it won't be printed. You can use some boolean variable and set it when you find an ID to True, after reading the next line set it again to False and use it in a second condition. However, this is not a ideal solution.

Comment: @CoryKramer  yes

Answer (score 1):

You must specify how do you want to read your file. The "new line" default delimiter is being used here. Check out the [Build-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) and take a look of  `open()` .

> "...When reading input from the stream, if newline is None, universal newlines mode is enabled. Lines in the input can end in '\n', '\r', or '\r\n'".

You must specify the delimiter in the stream in order to be read as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like csv reader.

```
import csv
with open('test_file.txt', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row[0])
```

Comment: I'm not expert on csv.reader but I'm not sure it will work differently in this situation. Not without some condition checking, in case there are more lines with an ID.